# Method returns null in simple JFrame

Tags: java, swing, class, object, hashmap

My `.get()` method in the `Class` `Solv` does not seem to be able to catch the `String` `chosen1`. If I do `System.out.print(print)` then `null` is returned. Why is this happening?
What I want to do is be able to select an item from a `ComboBox`, and then when I click a `JButton`, a corresponding value appears in a `JTextField`.

Here is my `JFrame Class` :

```
public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/* static field variables */
private String chosen1;

public JFrame() {
    initComponents();
}

/* Auto-generated code for the JForm here*/

/*method for when button is clicked on JForm*/                                                 
private void button1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    chosen1 = (String)combo_solvents.getSelectedItem();
    JFrame obj = new JFrame();
    String print = obj.run_s();
    textField.setText(print);
}    

public String run_s(){
    Solv s = new Solv(chosen1);
    String shift = s.return_shift();
    return shift;
    }

/* main method */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    // Auto-generated code here
    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    }

/* Variables declaration - do not modify */                     
private javax.swing.JButton button1;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> combo_impurity;
private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> combo_solvents;
private javax.swing.JTextField textField;
private javax.swing.JTextField textField2;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Here is my `Solv class` :

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Solv {

private final String shiftvalue;

/* class constructor */

Solv(String str){ 

HashMap<String, String> hmap_s = new HashMap<>();

hmap_s.put("CDCl3", "7.26");
hmap_s.put("D2O", "4.79");
hmap_s.put("CD2Cl2", "5.32");
hmap_s.put("DMSO-d6", "2.50");
hmap_s.put("Acetone-d6", "2.05");
hmap_s.put("Benzene-d6", "7.16");
hmap_s.put("Acetonitrile-d3", "1.94");
hmap_s.put("Methanol-d4", "3.31");

/* get the value from the key */
shiftvalue = hmap_s.get(str);
}

/* return the value */
String return_shift()
{
return shiftvalue;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class JFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame
```

Use a proper name for your class. The class names should be descriptive and should certainly not be "JFrame" which is the class you are extending.

```
chosen1 = (String)combo_solvents.getSelectedItem();
JFrame obj = new JFrame();
String print = obj.run_s();
textField.setText(print);
```

Why would you create a new "frame" object when an item is selected in the combobox?

Comment: In answer to your second question: I don't know. That was stupid.  I changed that and now it works. Thanks